# Is an accidental considered off key?

Tags: terminology, key, accidentals

If you have a song with accidentals and you sing it, are you then singing off key? And if you are in the key of C major for example, and in the song a D is raised to a D# with an accidental and instead of the D# you sing a D. Does that mean that you are singing off key?

Comment: If you sing a D instead of the D# that is written then it means nothing more than that you are singing the wrong note.  The accidental, despite its name, is there on purpose.  Artistic licence brands this a [modal tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)).

Comment: @J... _D#_ is not included in any of the modes of C Major. _D#_ is simply a chromatic tone - could be used as a passing tone from _D_ to _E_ - both of them diatonic to C major. D# is not _modal_.

Comment: @Stinkfoot I mean "modal" more generally (ie: moving beyond the diatonic).  The world is larger than seven greeks.

Comment: @J... IDK what modal has to do with it - modal is not the opposite of diatonic - on the contrary.  In this case, it's probably a chromatic passing tone - nothing to do with modes. Greeks or not, D# is not in any of the modes of C Major, no matter how you slice it or dice it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

'Off key' often means 'out of tune', so if the singer is singing an accidental properly, they may well be 'in tune', but 'out of key'. The accidental D# isn't *diatonic* (meaning a note from the key) so it could be thought of as 'off key', but a more apposite term would be 'out of the key'.

Comment: The words "succinct" and "concise" both mean "short", but "out of the key" is roughly twice as long as "off key" :-). Did you perhaps mean "precise" or "apt", or something like that?

Comment: @psmears - thanks for your input. Concise is still appropriate for what I wanted - it was not meant to mean 'this is shorter', merely 'this is short'. However, on reflection, it's edited. Approved now?! It's good to have things pointed out though...  Maybe I could have used 'pointed?

Comment: I like "apposite" :-)

Comment: In my experience, the phrase "off key" exclusive means "out of tune" or "off pitch". While it *could* grammatically be interpreted as referring to accidentals, I've never heard it used this way. Could be a question for the English SE if someone really wants to drill for examples / accuracy.

Comment: I had to look up the definition of "apposite". It made me smile.

Comment: @skinnypeacock - I'm happy for you! It's just that it was the most *apposite* word to use...

Answer (score 4):

Accidentals are used for all kinds of reasons. A D# in the key of C, alongside a B and an F#, would make a V/iii chord, for example, which is a perfectly legitimate chord in the key of C.

Or it could indicate a temporary modulation—a *change* of key—to E major or B major, or e minor for that matter. In that case, D# is "in key," despite what the key signature says.

Point is, accidentals aren't actually "outside the key" at all. They just indicate that something interesting is happening harmonically.

Answer (score 2):

```
Does that mean that you are singing off key?
```

Your question is not quite comprehensible as stated:

As far as the singer goes, whether it's `on key` or `off key` is irrelevant. If the music says **`D#`** and you sing **`D`** , you are singing **the wrong note**: It's not the note the composer wanted you to sing, regardless of whether or not it's `off key`.

Are you simply asking about semantics? Terminology? Regardless, `Off Key` is not a technical term, so it's difficult to have such a discussion.

The first question to ask here boils down to your title, which I'd translate as *Is **`D#`** diatonic to C Major?* - meaning is it one of the notes of the C major scale. But the answer to that question simple: D# clearly is not diatonic to C Major - it's an accidental - a note outside the parameters of the key/key signature in question. You knew that before you asked the question - that's why you asked it.

So the real question is this:  *Since D# is not part of the C major scale,  why is D# found in a piece of music that has the key signature of C Major? What functions might D# serve in the key of C Major?*  Is it right or wrong, is it `in key` or `off key` aren't particularly relevant to anything - that's how the music is written, and so we need to deal with it.  **What interests us as musicians or musical theoreticians is how would D# function in C Major** - we need to understand the music we are dealing with.

To get a definitive answer to that question, we'd have to see the whole sheet, or ask the composer.

Offhand the simple explanation is that D# is serving as a chromatic passing tone between D and E. Such chromatic (non-diatonic) passing tones are extremely common - it's fair to say they're ubiquitous in virtually all genres - they add color, depth and smoothness to music.

@JohnMGant in his answer gave some other good reasons for why we might encounter D# in music with a key signature of C Major.

Answer (score -2):

Every accidental indicates a modulation, or a feint towards one, otherwise, they'd be in the key signature. No one would consider a modulation "off key" or "out of the key" because it's intentional, and those refer to mistakes. In common practice tonality, almost always, if you see a sharp, it's the 7 of the key you're moving to; flats are the 4 of the key you're moving to, just as the last sharp in the key signature is the 7 of the key, the last flat is the 4 of the key.

Comment: This isn't true at all that _every_ accidental indicates a modulation. For example, in A minor you'll see a G# as the leading to to emphasize the tonic, but you'll never see it in the key signature.  Chromaitizm can also use accidentals and does not always mean you are modulating .

Comment: even in the common practice period this isn't true. It could be modulation, it could be a secondary chord (like a secondary dominant), or it could just be a chromatic embellishment like neoplatain and augmented 6th chords. And the example I gave is pure common practice period and doesn't fit what you are saying.